# Is IMAP suitable to use for an application mail server?

Tags: imap

I have an application that needs to read and parse emails from a mail server.   hMailServer allows me to route mail into an IMAP folder rather than forwarding it to a pop3 account.   Is IMAP fast enough to use as an applications mail server?

Comment: "Fast enough" is hard to answer, please quantify otherwise the answer must be "yes it may or may not be"...

Comment: An application that processes thousands of emails per hour?

Answer (score 0):

The way of fetching the mail data would be more or less same in both the protocols POP and IMAP. In pop u would do retr and in IMAP it is fetch. It has to be the connection speed that would matter. BTW both the protocols are meant to be scaled for millions of mail data and thousands of concurrent connections.